# Error in running mobile app code in Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, gradle

I am a beginner programmer. Recently I wanted to program an android app on Visual Studio. I created a project in Basic Application (Android,Gradle). I tried to run the program **without** even writing any code but it seems it gives me this stupid error

```
    MSB3073 The command "gradlew.bat -p "C:\Users\burak\source\repos\firstandroidapp\firstandroidapp\app"  assemblex86Debug" exited with code 1.
```

This is the error line

```
    <Exec Command="%(GradlePackage.ToolName) $(GradleParameters)" WorkingDirectory="$(WorkingDirectory)"/>
```

And the Java file is ok.

```
package com.firstandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class firstandroidapp extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Create a TextView and set its text to "Hello world" */
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello World!");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I am looking forward for your replies bcs I'm about to lose my mind here.

I tried installing Gradle, and set up the path, but it didn't work. I tried reinstalling visual studio but nothing again.

Comment: Try running gradle in a terminal, e.g., `gradlew assemblex86Debug`. Or check if VS Code can show you the Gradle output. It should print error messages. Quick guesses: your code isn't in the right folder, or you didn't put the dependencies in the build script. If that doesn't fix it, [edit] your question and add your `build.gradle`. Be more specific about what you mean by "it didn't work". What exactly did you do, and what happened? See [ask].

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the reply